# quarkus http calls load test results 1000 requests - 16 seconds vs 65 seconds

Tags: quarkus

**Test 1:**

```
@Path("/performance")
public class PerformanceTestResource {

    @Timeout(20000)
    @GET
    @Path("/resource")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response performanceResource() {

        final String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.println(name);

        Single<Data> dataSingle = null;

                try {
                    dataSingle = Single.fromCallable(() -> {
                        final String name2 = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                        System.out.println(name2);
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        return new Data();
                    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    int a = 1;
                }

        return Response.ok().entity(dataSingle.blockingGet()).build();
    }

}
```

---

The test itself [see also](https://github.com/Sergey80/rxjava2samples/blob/master/src/main/java/rxjava2/samples/LoadTestUtilSample.java) for the `callPeriodically` definition:

```
@QuarkusTest
public class PerformanceTestResourceTest {

        @Tag("load-test")
        @Test
        public void loadTest() throws InterruptedException {

            int CALL_N_TIMES = 1000;
            final long CALL_NIT_EVERY_MILLISECONDS = 10;

            final LoadTestMetricsData loadTestMetricsData = LoadTestUtils.callPeriodically(
                                                                                    this::callHttpEndpoint,
                                                                                    CALL_N_TIMES,
                                                                                    CALL_NIT_EVERY_MILLISECONDS
                                                                            );

            assertThat(loadTestMetricsData.responseList.size(), CoreMatchers.is(equalTo(Long.valueOf(CALL_N_TIMES).intValue())));

            long executionTime = loadTestMetricsData.duration.getSeconds();

            System.out.println("executionTime: " + executionTime + " seconds");

            assertThat(executionTime , allOf(greaterThanOrEqualTo(1L),lessThan(20L)));
        }
```

**Results test 1:**

**executionTime**: 16 seconds

Test 2: same but **without @Timeout** annotation:

**executionTime**: 65 seconds

**Q: Why? I think even 16 seconds is slow.
Q: How to make it faster: say to be 2 seconds for 1000 calls.**

I realise that I use `.blockingGet()` in the resource, but still, I would expect re-usage of the blocking threads.

P.S.
 I tried to go more 'reactive' returning `Single` or  `CompletionStage` to return from the responses - but this seems not yet ready (buggy on rest-easy side). So I go with simple .blockingGet()` and Response.

**UPDATE:  Reactive / RX Java 2 Way**

```
@path("/performance")
public class PerformanceTestResource {

//@Timeout(20000)
@GET
@Path("/resource")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Single<Data> performanceResource() {

    final String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();

    System.out.println(name);
    System.out.println("name: " + name);

    return Single.fromCallable(() -> {

        final String name2 = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.println("name2: " + name2);

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        return new Data();
    });
}
}`
```

[pom.xml](https://quarkus.io/guides/context-propagation):

io.smallrye
  smallrye-context-propagation-propagators-rxjava2




  org.jboss.resteasy
  resteasy-rxjava2

Then when run same test:

executionTime: **64 seconds**

The output would be something like:

```
name: vert.x-worker-thread-5 vert.x-worker-thread-9 name: vert.x-worker-thread-9 
name2: vert.x-worker-thread-9 
name2: vert.x-worker-thread-5
```

so, we are blocking the worker thread, that is use on REst/Resource side. That's hwy. **Then**:

If I `use:Schedulers.io()` to be on separate execution context for the sleep-1000-call:

```
return Single.fromCallable(() -> { ... }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

executionTime: **16 seconds**

The output will be something like this (see a new guy: RxCachedThreadScheduler)

```
name: vert.x-worker-thread-5
name2: RxCachedThreadScheduler-1683
vert.x-worker-thread-0
name: vert.x-worker-thread-0
vert.x-worker-thread-9
name: vert.x-worker-thread-9
name2: RxCachedThreadScheduler-1658
vert.x-worker-thread-8
```

Seems regardless: whether I use explicitly `blockingGet()` or not, i get the same result.

I assume if I am not blocking it it would be around **2-3 seconds**.

**Q:** I there a way to fix/tweak this from this point?

I assume the use of `Schedulers.io()` that brings the `RxCachedThreadScheduler` is the bottle neck in this point so I end up with the **16 seconds**, **200 io / io threads** is the limit by default? But should those be reused and not really be blocked. (don't think is good idea to set that limit to 1000).

**Q:** Or anyways: how would make app be responsive/reactive/performant as it should with Quarkus. Or what did I miss?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Maybe it is me.
In my callPeriodically(); i pass CALL_NIT_EVERY_MILLISECONDS = 10 milliseconds.
10 * 1000 = 10 000 - + ten seconds just to add the requests.

This, I set it to 0.

And got my 6 seconds for server 1000 simulations requests.

Still not 2-3 seconds. But 6.

Seems there is no difference if I use `.getBlocking` and return `Response` or returning `Single`.

--

But just to mention it, this hello world app take 1 second to process 1000 parallel requests. While Quarkus one is 6 seconds.

```
public class Sample2 {

    static final AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        final List<Single<Response>> listOfSingles = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

        for (int i=0; i< 1000; i++) {

//            try {
//                Thread.sleep(10);
//            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//                e.printStackTrace();
//            }

            final Single<Response> responseSingle = longCallFunction();

            listOfSingles.add(responseSingle);

        }

        Single<Response> last = Single.merge(listOfSingles).lastElement().toSingle();

        final Response response = last.blockingGet();

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Execution time: " + (end - start) / 1000);

        System.out.println(response);

    }

    static Single<Response> longCallFunction() {
        return Single.fromCallable( () -> { // 1 sec
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            int code = atomicInteger.incrementAndGet();
            //System.out.println(code);
            return new Response(code);
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }

}
```